# jQuery select next radio-button in matched radio-buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently struggeling with jQuery since I feel there are concepts lacking that I am used to from languages like PHP or C. I can't (yet) handle to find sufficient replacements so I could need a bit of support.

What I want to do is to simply check the *next radio button* in a jQuery *list of matched radio buttons*.
**Background:** Those radio-buttons are hidden through CSS, but each button represents one image, that is shown via HTML/CSS, when the specific radio button is checked.

Here is what I got so far:

```
var imageRadios = $('input[type="radio"][name="image-select"]');

function nextImage() {
    var nextImage = imageRadios.filter(':checked').eq(0).prop('checked', false).index(imageRadios) + 1;

    imageRadios.eq(nextImage).prop('checked', true);
}
```

On pageload, the first radio-button is checked hard-coded (`<input ... checked>`). `nextImage()` is called every 20 seconds by a timeout. The first call of `nextImage()` works fine (next radio-button is checked), but when it is called the second time, it unchecks the second radio button and checks the first one again. This toggling between first and second radio button happens endlessly. `console.log(nextImage);` after the first function-line gives either `1` or `0`.

Thanks in advance for help with this approach or a broad hint to any other approach!

---

**Note:** I know, that this function does not yet handle the jump from last to first element, once the end of the list is reached.

---

**Edit 1:** The relevant HTML (dynamically generated by PHP), as asked for:

```
<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-0" checked>
<div class="image">...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-1">
<div class="image">...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-2">
<div class="image">...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-3">
<div class="image">...</div>

...
```

---

**Edit 2:** JSFiddle as requested: https://jsfiddle.net/y7p7L68b/

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML too?

Comment: @MoisheLipsker I edited the question to include the HTML.

Comment: remove eq(0), radio button can be checked only one at a time and create jsfiddle plz

Comment: @IvanKaraman JSFiddle added, eq(0) removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var imageRadios = $('input[type="radio"][name="image-select"]');

function nextImage() {
    var nextImage = imageRadios.filter(':checked').prop('checked', false);
  var ind = imageRadios.index(nextImage);
    ++ind;
    if(ind >= imageRadios.length)ind = 0;
    imageRadios.eq(ind).prop('checked', true);
}

setInterval(nextImage, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-0" checked>
<div class="image">1...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-1">
<div class="image">2...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-2">
<div class="image">3...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-3">
<div class="image">4...</div>
```

Comment: This works, I implemented it in my program. Analyzing your changes brought me to the assumption that I was using index() the wrong way round. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css general sibling selector `~` to find the next sibling with a certain criteria.

```js
var radioSelector = 'input[type="radio"][name="image-select"]';
var imageRadios = $(radioSelector);

function nextImage() {
    var nextImage = imageRadios.filter(':checked ~ ' + radioSelector)[0];
    $(typeof nextImage !== 'undefined' ? nextImage : imageRadios[0]).prop('checked', true);
}
setInterval(nextImage, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-0" checked>
<div class="image">...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-1">
<div class="image">...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-2">
<div class="image">...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-3">
<div class="image">...</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I accepted Ivan Karamans answer as it is a more direct solution to my question. This works nontheless!

Answer (score 0):

I would propose that you should remove the radio button if they do not serve any other purpose than showing the respective image and just use the divs like this:

```js
// Set any timeout in ms
var time = 1000;
var divs = $('.img-holder');

function toggleImg(index) {  
  divs.hide();    
  divs.eq(index).show();  
  if (index === divs.length) {
    toggleImg(0);    
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() { toggleImg(index + 1); }, time);
  }  
}

toggleImg(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-holder">img-1</div>
<div class="img-holder">img-2</div>
<div class="img-holder">img-3</div>
<div class="img-holder">img-4</div>
```

Comment: This is no solution, since it breaks No-Javascript compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter like this:

```
var imageRadios = $('input[type="radio"][name="image-select"]');

var nextImage = (function(elements) {
    var current = 0, length = elements.length;
    return function () {
        current = current%length;
        elements.eq(current).prop('checked', false);
        elements.eq(current++).prop('checked', true);
    };

})(imageRadios);

setInterval(nextImage, 1000);
```

```js
var imageRadios = $('input[type="radio"][name="image-select"]');

var nextImage = (function(elements) {
    var current = 0, length = elements.length;
    return function () {
        current = current%length;
        elements[current].checked = false;
        elements[current++].checked = true;
    };

})(imageRadios);

setInterval(nextImage, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-0" checked>
<div class="image">...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-1">
<div class="image">...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-2">
<div class="image">...</div>

<input type="radio" name="image-select" id="image-3">
<div class="image">...</div>
```